# What does "EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample[]" do?

Tags: functions, undocumented

I found the undocumented `` EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample[] `` by browsing the lists of available symbols, but I have no clue about its purpose.

The name is intriguing!

So far I found the following:

- Accepts 2 or 3 arguments
- Returns an `Integer` (1, 10, 15, 31, 100 ...)
- For the first two arguments it seems to need equalities and boolean expressions (I didn't try quantifiers yet). Like in

  ```
  EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample[r == r + 1  && r == 2, b == 1]
  ```
- For the third argument, almost anything is allowed
- The numeric result seems to be connected to some feature of the equation system, but not sure to which one.

For example:

```
EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample[r == a + 1  , a == 1]
(*
-> 31
*)

EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample[r == a + 1  , r == a]
(*
-> 100
*)
```

Any suggestions or ideas about how to use this?

**Edit**

Some additional info, mostly provided by @Rojo:

```
Names["EquationalLogic`*"] // Column
(*
 "EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample"
 "EquationalLogic`FindProof"
 "EquationalLogic`Prove"
 "EquationalLogic`$MaxCounterexampleSearchSize"
     "EquationalLogic`$ProverOptions"
*)
```

All interesting names!

Now, look at this:

```
EquationalLogic`FindProof[y == x, y == 2 && x == 2]
(*
{ProofObject[
  InitialLemma[1, 2 == x],
  InitialLemma[2, 2 == y],
  InitialHypothesis[3, y == x],
  OrientRule[4, 2 -> x, Reason[1, Identity, 1]],
  ApplyLemma[5, 2 -> x, 2 == y, 0, 1, DeducedLemma[5, x == y, SupportingReason[2, x, x, 4, 0]]],
  OrientRule[6, x -> y, Reason[5, Identity, 2]],
  ApplyLemma[8, y -> x, y == x, 0, 1, SufficesToShow[8, True, SupportingReason[3, x, x, 6, 1]]],
  FinalGoal[9, True, EndReason[8]]
  ], True}
```

However, hold your expectations:

```
EquationalLogic`FindProof[2 y == 2 x, y == 2 && x == 2]
(*
{ProofObject[], False}
*)
```

If you run

```
Trace[EquationalLogic`FindProof[x == 0, x == 0], TraceInternal -> True]
```

among a lot of non human gibberish, you will find a lot of references to

```
EquationalLogicDump`skolem____$
```

And just for your reference, there is the [**Skolem normal form**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form)

Comment: http://infosuite.duke4.net/e1l5sm2.png

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Don't try to scare me off with that. Everybody is telling me the same since kindergarten.

Comment: Scare you off? Not at all! The screen shot is an "Easter egg" from a game: a reward of sorts for exploring beyond the intended limits.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ohhh sorry .. I believed you were looking for a job at the [Thought Police](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_Police)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty cool; `` EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample `` is still mysterious (at least to me), but I managed to get it to do something more interesting than spit back numbers.

```
EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample[f[a, i] == a, f[a, a] == a]
(* {{f -> ({{1, 2}, {1, 1}}[[##1]] &), a -> 1}, {i -> 2}} *)
```

It appears the the first clause satisfies the logical constraints from the second argument (i.e., the assumptions) and the second clause makes the first clause false.

This is speculation, but perhaps `` EquationalLogic`FindCounterexample `` returns a number when it has some kind of error.

---

`` EquationalLogic`FindProof `` and `` EquationalLogic`Prove `` appears to be implementing a term-rewriting based proof system (like [Equational Logic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquationalLogic.html) from Mathworld).  This reminds me of `SIMP_TAC` from the computer proof assistant [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/tutorial_220.pdf).

A key difference is that the logic of this prover does not follow the following rules from equational logic:
$$\frac{a=b}{f(a)=f(b)}$$
$$\frac{a=b}{a(x)=b(x)}$$

Seems to work fine as a term-rewriting prover despite lacking those rules. Here's a little proof in [combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) using the `EquationalLogic` prover:

```
EquationalLogic`Prove[ForAll[x, ((s@k)@k)@x == x], 
                        ForAll[{x, y}, (k@x)@y == x] && 
                        ForAll[{f, g, x}, ((s@f)@g)@x == (f@x)@(g@x)]]
(* True *)
```

You can do a lot of this stuff with [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/), if you want a point of comparison.

As a final note, since it is apparently possible to express combinatory logic in this system, it is possible to ask the `EquationalLogic` prover to prove an undecidable proposition. From my own experiments, it will eat up all of your memory if you ask it to prove something it can't.

Comment: Matt, welcome to the site, and thanks a lot for your very interesting answer!

Comment: Note: we prefer to post here executable code, and if it helps _also_ the corresponding TEX expressions. You may want to edit your answer and add the Mathematica code for your last expression.

Comment: BTW ... What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @Matt This is a very nice answer. I've edited your post to include copyable code, staying true to your latex equivalent, so that others can easily copy-paste and test it for themselves. Feel free to add a math equivalent in latex if it helps. There is generally no need to pretty print mathematica expressions (and usually `InputForm` is used here)

Comment: @belisarius:  Okay, I'll make sure to follow the convention in the future. I'm using Mathematica 8.0

Comment: @R.M - Thanks. @ in Mathematica are right-associative, which is a little different than in combinatory logic and lambda calculus (where function application is left associative).  So I fixed that...

Comment: Matt, is that what you intended? This gives `s[k][k][x]`, whereas using composition gives `s[k[k[x]]]` and they're both different. I thought the latter was closer to your latex expression (yes, the associativity had to be fixed), but I could be wrong, because this is not my field

Comment: This is what I intended. ``s[k][k]`` is the *identity function* in combinatory logic.  Back in the 20s when this stuff was being invented, Schoenfinkle and Church treated function application as left associative.  I agree that right associativity makes more sense for Mathematica.  If you would like a reference, see Schoenfinkle's *Building Blocks of Logic* (1924), $\S3$. Note that Schoenfinkle wrote "C" instead of "K".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the reference, Matt :)